# Text on an OLED display connected to an Arduino Nano won't stop scrolling

Tags: arduino, adafruit

I am coding a tachometer. I am still in the early stages and this is the first time I have dealt with a display. At the moment I am simply reading the value from an IR sensor and displaying it on the display. For some reason the number either scrolls left to right or just straight down. Can anyone see a reason as to why the number isn't static?

```
int irsensor = 4;
int sensorvalue;
unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
unsigned int rpm = 0;
volatile unsigned int counter = 0;


#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>

#define SCREEN_WIDTH 128 
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 64

Adafruit_SSD1306 display(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, &Wire, -1);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(irsensor, INPUT);
  display.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC, 0x3C);
  delay(2000);
  display.clearDisplay();
  display.setTextSize(1);
  display.setTextColor(WHITE);
  display.setCursor(0,30);
}

void loop() {
  sensorvalue = digitalRead(irsensor);
  Serial.println(sensorvalue);
  display.clearDisplay();
  display.print(sensorvalue);
  display.display();

  
}
```

Comment: In this library, `clearDisplay()` doesn't do *anything* other than clear the display - in particular, the cursor position remains exactly where it was, at the end of the previously shown number.  You need to explicitly set the cursor position for each update.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `display.clearDisplay();` only clean display but the cursor remains in last position so you need to reset it to your desired position; same as in your `setup()`

```
void loop() {
  sensorvalue = digitalRead(irsensor);
  Serial.println(sensorvalue);
  display.clearDisplay();
  display.setCursor(0,30);
  display.print(sensorvalue);
  display.display();
}
```